# Outlook adding space or padding to the left of my table

Tags: html, email, outlook

I'm creating an email signature in HTML. The signature is laid out in a table, but for some inexplicable reason, Outlook adds ridiculous padding to the entire table and between the rows which aren't supposed to be there.

I've tried nested tables, "ghost" td's etc, none helped.

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="bodyTable">

    <tr>
        <td width="35%" style="font-family: Arial,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0; line-height: 14pt; color: #000">
            <span style="color: #D4232B; font-size: 11pt"><strong>Name</strong></span><br /><span style="font-weight: bold;">Title</span><br /><br />Number | Mobile<br /><a target="_blank" style="color: #000; text-decoration: underline;" href="#">www.domain.com</a>
        </td>

        <td style="font-family: Arial,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; padding-left: 0; line-height: 14pt; color: #000"><img src="imagelocation"></td>

        <td style="font-family: Arial,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 7pt; padding-top: 3px; padding-left: 10px; color: #000;">
            <img src="imagelocation"><br /><br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum.. <br />Authorised Financial Services Provider FSPNUM VAT NUMBER
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="font-family: Arial,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 10px; color: #6D6E71">
            <strong>Disclaimer:</strong> <br />The information contained in this communication from the sender is confidential. It is intended solely for use by the recipient and others authorized to receive it. If you are not the recipient, you are hereby notified that any disclosure, copying, distribution or taking action in respect of the contents of this information is strictly prohibited and may be unlawful.
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

I really want the table to be aligned with the body of my email content.

Here's a snip of what's currently happening.

[image: Signature issue]

Answer (score 0):

Added `margin:0` which fixed the alignment issues.